# Compilation error when using a variable initialized by an enum value inside a switch

Tags: typescript, enums

[Playground Link](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#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-AFVRMgBrJiEKaGWTVI7XyXUY3rY4FDVxMSXE60Ku2eLCO53RLU8ptdFuCw0i8IS6IUXu2pXEoeZ+vc1ETgUG9smpIpNLd+GLxXzwdqsYUd2e72+-0gQMhsMRu-R2O8CpA2oVsEptOrsY6CAA)

I'm having a compilation error with the code provided in the playground link and I don't understand why.

I'm creating a variable with a value of an enum:

[image]

intellisense tell me that the type of my variable is inferred as I expected: ValidatorMessageState. Like when assigning true/false to a variable, typescript infers a boolean and not true or false as type.

then I switch over it:
[image]
Now intellisense tells me the type of my variable has changed even if I've done nothing between creating it and switching on it.
Variable have now the type of the value of the enum and not the enum.

Another thing I've found strange: if I introduce some closure, typescript does not give me errors (I've commented this part in the playground)

[image]

I suppose I'm doing something wrong here, but I don't see what. Can someone could explain it to me?

Updated playground: [Playground Link](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=63&pc=2#code/KYOwrgtgBAaghgGwJYBM4BcD2AnAssAZwLgHNgBldDYKAbwFgAoKFqAUW2xygF4oByYJxz8ANE1ZQA6nGwgkIErwEB3WfMViJrAJIgAZjggYkmEMv4LD2Y+lMh+TAL5NQkKAGFMCbg2asAJWAUcX8WAE1gBB8VUMkAIQQwGlZnJiYEYHQoYwAPSmo2EABjTDB0IWDleGQ0LDxCYjICioA6Di5sAG50xkzs7EIwBHR4gE8a1AxuFh4AbT9JCEbSQgAuBe1JFgIqCrXYRCn6-CJVluBWvWtbezjtlmWzsgP+dAALJAIoL6g4cysRhMZkcYSgTlEiweUF21AOkzqOFOTQoe0uMjkChI9weTxRrw+v1+cCgakxmi24IAus4aX0sjDQBUSjQ+Px+D1GEwkPooAAKQYEYajCZHRHYACUdEpguF4wR02wrWsbDgxXeAt4AD5pWDJDz+Uq8asCFKodDWEaVmQCMqcKr1XzoDwdeaLdsAG6yKDFMCcJkXZQQVqwipQAD84cOtUVyPOaPawm6UAA9CmfryQJgYWioAAHQbFL5VF1QQnfYnmISdSnu1gEFRIdDq-l5C5FUrlSooM21uvbYpwAg0BUna2o6iJzprPv96Fpv4IQZwFBjHJwXKzufbABGy4A1pzt9DB8Po8ckeOLq0MRoSDO9cftganSHczwP+fxXHmgmOjhe0fJ9oTbNEOzKCpBhQaoxVjK8-yTI9gOhFwgOQvdgDgQ8tznU8R1gsdngnNpriBOwzAfZDoRfYNQxoABCT9R0vIjr1ImxgRAQCqLrUDChKCDu2UX1-RAdALiQnjWFQqTJAwrDJOQlBgH0OBhQOUoQF2KAAH1gFyd41N2A4QGAD0hCDDd2wErsoK6KB5OwtCLRkp9hzE0BihoABqPg+Xc5kvIjARRAEKBXn4KVvJyVpjTIRSXIlLdXJYJwJU5VCvWwH1vBwA4vB8bomAbJsWydKywJsyDgm41g8K-ODWIQ6ct1KQrlAKnBWiCFAEtYRzFPq5iGiaydbyxSiT1y7K+E6pVImiTAVD6lgBspIaCJYlE2IMMj7Emh42u4WbptaRJkhWhyD0U5TVPUnKtOyPSDKM9ATLMiy+D4ipwNs4J7LWxgnCAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature, not a bug :)

This is Typescript doing [control flow analysis](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/control-flow-based-type-analysis-in-typescript). The control flow analysis only start kicking in in certain code structures, like a switch statement.

Once you reach the switch statement, typescript compiler tries to narrow down the type of `maxStateEncoutered`. And in your case it can only be `ValidatorMessageState.Error` as that was the only assignement. And typescript isn't wrong about this... If you assigned your variable in some dynamic way (as in: a function that returns `ValidatorMessageState`) the error would go away.

As for the code inside the `forEach`, typescript can't reason about code inside closures/callbacks. The gist of the reason being it doesn't know when this code will run. Sure, in `forEach` it will run immediately, but typescript doesn't know that about the function. In a function like `addEventListener` the function you pass can run at any time, and `maxStateEncoutered` might change until then, so it can no longer deduce that `maxStateEncoutered` is of specific type `ValidatorMessageState.Error`. If you change `maxStateEncoutered` from `let` to `const`, you will see this error inside the `forEach` as well.

Comment: Ok thanks you answer. It's pretty much what i supected. But It would be nice that something like 
let maxStateEncoutered: ValidatorMessageState = ValidatorMessageState.Error; 
works because i gave the type.

Comment: `let maxStateEncoutered = ValidatorMessageState.Error as ValidatorMessageState;` will work, as not typescript won't be able to narrow down the type.

But if you only assign the variable once, why the switch statement? and if the code in the playground is just a short example and your actual code you will have more assignments, then there it should work without changes

Comment: You're right, the code in first playground have been simplfied. I've put a second playground at the end of my post with what i'm trying to achieve here. Basically, I browse a list of message with a state and increase a global severity when I'm encoutering a higher severity. The goal is to pick a color.

Comment: ah, I now understand your use case. Indeed there not much to do here (at least as far as I know) beyond the workaround above `let maxStateEncoutered = ValidatorMessageState.Error as ValidatorMessageState;`

The issue in github that describes your problem: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998 (though I doubt it will ever be fixed...)

Comment: thanks for the link, its nice to see I'm not the only one with the problem. I will extract a function as you proposed in your first answer.